# Natural vs Innate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I wonder what do you normally call those talents of an individual which have been with them from the beginning?

I know two [fixed phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=natural+talent%2C+innate+talent&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnatural%20talent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinnate%20talent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binnate%20talent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInnate%20talent%3B%2Cc0):

> 1. Natural talents
> 2. Innate talents

Also I need to know what do you call a person who has such a quality?

> 1. Naturally talented person
> 2. Innately talented person

As you see, Ngram shows that comparing to the word "innate", the adjective "natural" has a more prevalence in this case.

Please let me know whether they mean the same thing and that is just a matter if preference to use each one!

Answer (score 1):

Innate is the better word to convey a talent that one possessed at birth.

Natural works and will probably be understood in context but natural can be interpreted to mean things other than possessed at birth.  If your talent is playing the violin and my talent is shooting lightning bolts from my fingers, your talent might be called natural and mine might be called unnatural. Although it's doubtful that either is innate.

Answer (score 1):

While both "innate and "natural" can be used to refer to an ability one has had since birth, there is a difference.

The common collocated phrases

> innate sense
>   innate ability

can be used to refer to a talent or ability which does not need any coaching or further learning

> He has an *innate* sense of timing.
>   She has an *innate* ability for design.

For example, an [idiot savant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savant_syndrome)'s ability is *innate*.

Whereas another commonly collocated phrase

> naturally talented

can be used to refer to having an ability which can be (and possibly needs to be) further trained

> He is a *natural* when it comes to playing sports.
>   She is *naturally talented* at singing.

These mean the base (foundation) abilities and talent exist and can be further refined.

Comment: Peter thank you for responding to me, but the question is that if based on what you cited here, my second sentence sounds natural to you or it doesn't.